# Why does String's bytes: and cString: initializers give different results here?

Tags: swift, string

Converting bytes to string is very common ...

```
import Foundation

var data = Data(bytes: [65,66,67,0,0,0,0,0,0])
let str0 = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)

let str1 = data.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<CChar>)->String? in
    return String(cString: p, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

comparing the strings

```
print(str0 == str1) // false   ??????????
```

was a little bit surprice to me.

Next snippet explains, why the strings are different

```
print(str0 as Any, str0 ?? "", str0?.characters.count as Any)
print(str1 as Any, str1 ?? "", str1?.characters.count as Any)
```

it prints

```
Optional("ABC\0\0\0\0\0\0") ABC Optional(9)
Optional("ABC") ABC Optional(3)
```

Is this behavior expected?

At fist sight I understood Rob's answer, but ...

```
let str2 = data.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<Int8>)->String? in
    return String(utf8String: p)
}
```

gave me 3 characters long string. Yes I know CChar is typealias for Int8, but does it means, that p represents CString automatically?

Finally, I checked the same **in IBM Sandbox**
http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5942a7d7c0be7f183ad81525

In both cases, the resulting **String is the same, with 3 characters**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is expected.

The strings supported by the C language and its standard library are terminated by ASCII NUL, which is byte value zero, and don't have an explicit length. So a C-string cannot contain a NUL.

But in Swift (and many other languages), every string is stored with a length and so it can contain any number of NULs anywhere in the string.

You created `str0` from a `Data`, and a `Data` also has a length. So the initializer you used for `str0` can create a string containing NULs. But you created `str1` using the `init(cString:encoding:)` initializer, which specifically says that the input is a C-string, which is terminated by the first NUL. So `str1` cannot contain any NULs.

Comment: I didn't know about this "it can contain any number of NULs anywhere ", I have to check rest of my code :-) Thanks!

Comment: and what about String(utf8String: p) ?? It gives me the same result as String(cString: p, encoding: .utf8) (3 characters)

Comment: The [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) say that `init?(utf8String: UnsafePointer<CChar>)` "Produces a string created by copying the data from a given C array of UTF8-encoded bytes.". So this initializer also assumes a C-string.

Comment: `String(utf8String:)` also takes a C-string as input and stops at the first NUL.

Comment: please, see my update and check what I got with open sourced swift (IBM Sandbox). Thank You in advance!

Comment: @paulvs if String(uft8String:) assumes that its parameter is C - string, it is not mentioned in the documentation. byte stream 0,0,0,0, .... is valid "standard"  utf8 sequence.

Comment: @user3441734: `String(uft8String:)` takes only a pointer as argument and no count. How should it determine how many bytes to read if not until a null termination?

Comment: The Swift documentation could definitely be improved here. As it happens, [`String(utf8String:)` simply forwards to `NSString(utf8String:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3b628d32fc10563331e8a24d60a8e7000d4c0024/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSStringAPI.swift#L226), and [`NSString(utf8String:)` is documented to take a NUL-terminated array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412128-init#).